# First-chance exception settings check state in Listview

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, access-violation

I'm getting the following error in the output window in Visual Studio:

`First-chance exception at 0x5d0d47af (msvcr100d.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.`

Each time this code is executed:

```
const int iItem = ListView_GetItemCount(hListOutput);

LVITEM lvI;

lvI.mask        = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_GROUPID;
lvI.iSubItem    = 0;
lvI.iGroupId    = 101;
lvI.iItem       = iItem;
lvI.pszText     = const_cast<LPWSTR>(mystr.c_str());

if (ListView_InsertItem(hListOutput, &lvI) != -1)
{
    ListView_SetCheckState(hListOutput, iItem, TRUE);
}
```

If I comment out the `ListView_SetCheckState`, I stop getting the access violation.

All items are being inserted and the item check states are being set.
But I would like to figure out why I am getting an access violation.

Comment: Did you remember to call `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle` to set the `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` extended style? `ListView_SetCheckState` is documented as working only with `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` list views.

Answer (score 1):

> ListView_SetCheckState(hListOutput, **iItem**, TRUE);

this one seems like error because it will point to a value one greater than the available in the list(since zero indexed).

try

```
unsigned int iItem1=iItem-3;//anything greater than zero..

ListView_SetCheckState(hListOutput,iItem1, TRUE);
```

Comment: I'm inserting the item before setting the check state, so that shouldn't be the problem. See updated code.

Comment: first check if the insertion is successful,however if my provided code is working then there must be insertion failure.otherwise let me know.

Comment: Insertion is successful. I'm inserting 4 items and all 4 are inserted. I also checked the return value to be sure and there was no problems there.

Comment: Tried setting `iItem` as `UINT` - no difference.

Comment: where is the code for `ListView_SetCheckState` defined . Watch out for call from this function to a .dll file which in turn throws the error while retriving the value .

Comment: It's a macro defined in `CommCtrl.h`

Comment: I believe that macro must again be call to some function in the msvcr100d.dll which in turn is doing memory access voilation . I guess so but I am not too sure about it as things are not very clear here and needs some debugging

Answer (score 0):

Is the return value of ListView_InsertItem equal to iItem?  The MSDN document indicates that the item index is returned from the insert function, so it probably would be safest to use that value when setting the check state.